# GGPLOT2 how to fill areas?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, visualization, geography

how can I fill with a solid color a area in a geographical map if the value in that area is within a certain interval of values?

I'm using this

```
right_join(prov2022, df, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Wage`)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( "white", "red"))
```

But it gives a color gradient in each area according with the value of the variable "Wage".

Now I need to have a solid red color (not gradient!) for all the areas that have a value between 700 and 1500.
How do I do that?

Comment: Try changing `aes(fill = Wage)` to `aes(fill = Wage > 700 & Wage < 1500)`, and change your `scale_fill_gradientn` to `scale_fill_manual(values = c('white', 'red'))`

Comment: To self-document your code (and make it a little more clear), perhaps `right_join(..) %>% mutate(middle = factor(between(Wage, 700, 1500), labels = c("Outside", "Inside"))) %>% ggplot(aes(fill = middle)) + ...`, as that will both label the legend and allow other aesthetics (if you expand the code) to also use it.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @AllanCameron in comment:

```
right_join(prov2022, df, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = Wage > 700 & Wage < 1500)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('white', 'red'))
```